# Reset navigator to home from different stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Suppose that I am at `Profile3`. I want to reset to `Stack1` (initial route of bottom navigator). How is that possible? I only able to reset to `Stack3`. But not `Stack1`.

If i try to replace the `Stack3` to `Stack1` or `Bottom1`, it will have error message. It seems that the stackreset must be from same stack navigator?

> Error: There is no route defined for key Stack1. Must be one of
>   Stack3, Profile3

**Reset Code**

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Stack3' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

**Navigation Code:**

```
  const Stack1 = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Stack1: Home1,
        Profile1: Profile
      }
    );

    const Stack2 = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Stack2: Home2,
        Profile2: Profile
      }
    );


    const Stack3 = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Stack3: Home3,
        Profile3: Profile
      }
    );

    const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
        Bottom1: Stack1,
        Bottom2: Stack2,
        Bottom3: Stack3
      }, {
          {
            initialRouteName: 'Bottom1',
     });

  export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Comment: How about just navigate to `Stack1` `this.props.navigation.navigate('Stack1')`?

Comment: @TuanLuong it will navigate to `stack1` but this will not reset the navigation afaik. I want to reset as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

    const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Stack1 ' })],
    });
    this.pr

    ops.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

if you want to reset 1 then replace that `Stack3` with `Stack1` , and on dispatch it will load that stack from the index 0

**EDIT :**

as we need to reset the main stack to we need to use `NavigationActions` instead of `StackActions` to perform reset

Let me know if that works

Comment: I have updated my code. Error: There is no route defined for key Stack1. Must be one of Stack3, Profile3

Comment: NavigationActions.reset is not a function i am using react navigation 4. This function has been depreacated since 3

Answer (score 0):

Try just replacing stack3 in your reset with stack1 from anywhere you want to reset the stack:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Stack1' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Update :

Found the fix, just need to use navigationState.index over props.getLastPosition() and add a check before the dispatch to see which tab is the current.

```
tabBarComponent: props => {
  const {navigation, navigationState} = props
  const jumpToIndex = index => {
    const lastPosition = navigationState.index
    const tab = navigationState.routes[index]
    const tabRoute = tab.routeName
    const firstTab = tab.routes[0].routeName

    lastPosition !== index && navigation.dispatch(pushNavigation(tabRoute))
    lastPosition === index && navigation.dispatch(resetNavigation(firstTab))
  }
  return <TabView.TabBarBottom {...props} jumpToIndex={jumpToIndex}/>
},
```

check this  link once [rn-issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/933)

hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: I have updated my code. Error: There is no route defined for key Stack1. Must be one of Stack3, Profile3. Not sure why all of u suggested this solution as it doesn't work.

Comment: wait, you can only reset that when you are in tab1. try that from tab1

Comment: yes, i know i can reset it from tab1. but i am in stack navigator on tab3 and i want to reset it to tab 1. What function should i use to reset?

Comment: this is a very old solution regarding react navigation v1. I am using v4.